# bash, delete all files with a pattern name

Tags: bash

- I need to delete all files with a pattern name:  `2020*.js`
- Inside a specific directory: `server/db/migrations/`
- And then show what it have been deleted: `| xargs``

I'm trying this:

```
find . -name 'server/db/migrations/2020*.js' #-delete | xargs
```

But nothing is deleted, and shows nothing.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
find server/db/migrations -type f -name '2020*.js' -delete -print
```

Answer (score 5):

The immediate problem is that `-name` only looks at the last component of the file name (so `2020xxx.js`) and cannot match anything with a slash in it. You can use the `-path` predicate but the correct solution is to simply delete these files directly:

```
rm -v server/db/migrations/2020*.js
```

The `find` command is useful when you need to traverse subdirectories.

Also, piping the output from `find` to `xargs` does not do anything useful; if `find` prints the names by itself, `xargs` does not add any value, and if it doesn't, well, `xargs` can't do anything with an empty input.

If indeed you want to traverse subdirectories, try

```
find server/db/migrations/ -type f -name '2020*.js' -print -delete
```

If your shell supports `**` you could equally use

```
rm -v server/db/migrations/**/2020*.js
```

which however has a robustness problem if there can be very many matching files (you get "command line too long"). In that scenario, probably fall back to `find` after all.

Answer (score -3):

You have try this:

```
find . -name 'server/db/migrations/2020*.js' | xargs rm
```

Comment: While _xargs_ works here, the _find_ tool has the more stable `-delete` option for just this case.